# Is there a monitor or converter I can use to watch 4 video outputs on one screen?

Tags: video-adapters, signal-processing

I have many video outputs that I would like to simultaneously overview with a control monitor, but I don't want to buy a monitor for each video output itself. So I'm looking for a similar solution what we can see at surveillance systems, where the monitor is connected to a DVR unit, which processes multiple camera images, and we can see them displayed in some kind of grid.

[image: DVR monitor]

Is there such a device for regular VGA or HDMI outputs? It doesn't matter if it is built into the monitor itself or if it has, for example, 4 or more inputs with one output I can connect to a monitor. It would be nice if the output layout could be configurable to different layout styles like in the picture below, but it isn't a requirement.

[image: Multiple video output layout styles]

Comment: If the purpose is to create a demo, then this [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638038/combining-videos-in-opencv-and-qt) can be of help!

Comment: Budget? Throughput?

Comment: @Gilles Doesn't matter.

Comment: What type of DVR do you use? Is it possible to run 3rd party software on it, does it have a central platform as an option?

Comment: @Gram I didn't said I have a DVR. That was just an example for what layout I'm looking for. I would be surprised if a DVR device would be prepared for this kind of usage. DVR inputs are usually not HDMI/VGA. Even in that case it wouldn't be the intended usage and I would also pay for other functionality that is not related to what I'm loking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [LG 43UD79](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-43UD79-B-4k-uhd-led-monitor)

This is a monitor/TV that supports 4 HDMI inputs. It can display a single input or all of them simultaneously.

[image: LG 43UD79 4 input]

It has multiple layout options and comes with a remote. There is a [video where you can see this feature in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42JvQnzOYSc).

[image: LG 43UD79 4 input layouts and remote]

It has been extensively reviewed:

- [Dave Lee](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vv1W0C920oE)
- [Bitwit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPrZzu2XcAU)
- [Linus Tech Tips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kYrQ-LOiXE)
- [Unbox Therapy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_7JKVuC9Bw)

Answer (score 6):

I currently use an LG 29UM67 which is a 21:9 monitor which supports the features you are talking about. I was able to get it on Amazon for about 350USD and it supports upto 4 inputs simultaneously, either with different inputs or daisy chaining I believe.

Here is a link to LG's website for the same - http://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-29UM67-P-ultrawide-led-monitor

Comment: That's awesome. I didn't realize a mainstream brand like LG made a multiple-input monitor. Nice recommendation!

Answer (score 5):

I have some potential options that may be helpful.

**Option 1: Using an in-between hardware solution**

One option would be **[Screens](http://skreens.com/)** a product that resides between the screen itself and your inputs. It is in Kickstarter now but allows you to customize a good number of inputs by running its own internal **[software](http://skreens.com/#skreensos)**. Another option that is available now from my understanding is the **[Cadent](http://saltlabs.net/cadent)**.

**Option 2: Using software at the source to split the image**

The cheapest option would be to use **[software](http://lifehacker.com/5519833/five-best-tools-for-managing-your-multi-monitor-setup)** on the host to do this for you, however I think this may not be an option based on the source of the content (camera or central DVR unit) you have.

**Option 3: The continued search for a screen with more than two hardware inputs**

Currently, most monitors/or TVs that allow multiple simultaneous input only allow two inputs and are in the expensive price range for example. For example I have the (as cheap as I could find 4k) **[Samsung LU28D590DS](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/monitors/LU28D590DS/ZA)**. It has two HDMI inputs that can be run at the same time. However as 4k becomes more mainstream there might be more options for simultaneous inputs.

Edit1: @Aditya Somani found one with four inputs

Edit2: @Nathan Osman Also found a [screen](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=04&l=en&sku=210-AHSQ) that should work.

---

On a side note, a DVI cable can be converted to HDMI though a cheap adapter. Likewise a Displayport adapters exist however are slightly more dependent on the source of the signal or [require an active signal processer](http://tommynation.com/displayport-dvi-adapters-explained/).

Comment: Here's a monitor that matches option #3: http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=04&l=en&sku=210-AHSQ